# In UnderscoreJS, is there a collection filter for matching any of the key-value pairs?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've got a query where I need to match against any multiple values. The _.where method is really close:

Here's the _where docs:

> where_.where(list, properties)  Looks through each value in the list,
>   returning an array of all the values that contain **all of the
>   key-value pairs** listed in properties.

```
 _.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});
 => [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
     {title: "The Tempest", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611}]
```

I'm needing a .whereAny method:

```
_.whereAny(listOfMovies, {director: "Tarantino", director: "Scorcese"});
=>[{title: "Pulp Fiction", director: "Tarantino", year:1996},{title:"Taxi", director: "Scorcese", year:1983}]
```

Where it will return an array of objects that match **any** of the supplied key value pairs. Am I missing this method, or is there a simple way to do it?

Many thanks!

*A more detailed explanation- I'm trying to filter a large list of objects with three checkboxes. Each item in the original data set has a property that corresponds to one of those three values. If you select checkbox 1 (value:Red), I will get a subset of the original data set containing only those items with key-value = Red. If you also select checkbox 2 (value:Orange), I will then need to query for both of those values, and so on.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://underscorejs.org/#filter so:

```
_.filter(listOfMovies, function(movie) { return movie.director == 'Tarantino' || movie.director == 'Scorcese'; });
```

Comment: And you can generalize this with `directors = [ ... ]` and `_(directors).include(movie.director)`.